# Chrome downloads page instead of showing

Tags: google-chrome, github, download, content-type, bitbucket

I have a strange Problem on github and bitbucket.
Chrome occasionally downloads a page instead of showing it. If I cancel the download and click again, it works.
I have a hunch it may be because the contenttype is application/x-gzip…
Has someone made similar experiences or a solution?
Thanks in advance!

**[EDIT]:** @genkev: The response mimetype is application/x-gzip. I have no idea, why its send this way or why its not shown regulary but requests the browser to download the file.
I wont say its neither a browserproblem nor a serverproblem, but its a (my) problem anyway.

```
{
  "startedDateTime": "2012-11-29T08:27:08.503Z",
  "time": 3,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": "Accept-Encoding",
        "value": "gzip,deflate,sdch"
      },
      {
        "name": "Accept-Language",
        "value": "de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cookie",
        "value": "uninteresting cookie"
      },
      {
        "name": "Connection",
        "value": "keep-alive"
      },
      {
        "name": "Accept-Charset",
        "value": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3"
      },
      {
        "name": "Host",
        "value": "github.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "User-Agent",
        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
      },
      {
        "name": "Accept",
        "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
      },
      {
        "name": "Referer",
        "value": "https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues"
      }
    ],
    "queryString": [],
    "cookies": [
      "some cookies"
    ],
    "headersSize": 1678,
    "bodySize": 0
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/0.9",
    "headers": [],
    "cookies": [],
    "content": {
      "size": 0,
      "mimeType": "application/x-gzip",
      "compression": 0
    },
    "redirectURL": "",
    "headersSize": 19,
    "bodySize": 0
  },
  "cache": {},
  "timings": {
    "blocked": 0,
    "dns": -1,
    "connect": -1,
    "send": 0,
    "wait": 0,
    "receive": 1,
    "ssl": -1
  },
  "pageref": "page_2"
}
```

Comment: Uh, how is Chrome supposed to "view" a gzip file?

Comment: I think it's related to your network connection such as proxy, etc. Sometimes when I get a bad network, Chrome always download a page instead of showing it.

Comment: this error occurs at work as well at home. Maybe its coincidence, but at least at home, I don't have a proxy.
It only occurs in Chrome!

Comment: I have this problem as well using Google Chrome on Linux 64bit. It used to be rare (maybe once a week) - but as of late it happens on every-other click. NOTE: I do not have a proxy or have an otherwise bad connection. You are not alone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem! It was caused by the Webug 1.2.3 FirePHP extension for Google Chrome. Don't know if future versions of this plugin also have this bug.

Comment: I apologize for this error in Webug — in the current version it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely an extension issue. For me it was "Hover Zoom 4.11.3" that caused this.